# Ignore a specific page when rewriting rules with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm wondering how I can tell wordpress rewrites to IGNORE a specific page, such as: `index.php?p=15`
I've tried several things, like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}!^/index.php?p=15 !-d
```

Or trying to specify the rule before the wordpress rules etc, but nothing has worked out so far.

Any ideas on how I can make this work?

Comment: Can you explain why you want/need this? What goal does this accomplish?

Comment: I have built up a lot of pages using templates, and now I have built a forms template that should act differently depending on the URL.
So the reason is that I want to grab segments from the URL in my controller to parse different kind of HTML, but it still goes through the same page.
So shorter said, multiple URLs, 1 page.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the following code, and it seems to work properly :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}:::%{QUERY_STRING} !test\.php:::p=15$
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Everything is redirect to `/index.php` except for `test.php?p=15`.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't fix the issue.